# C append/concat strings "on the fly"

Tags: c, concatenation, append, ansi-c

I thought it's possible to concatenate strings (char arrays) in C on the fly.

```
char* str1= "hello" " " "world";
```

But when I try the following I'll receive an error message (Too few arguments to function fopen). why?

```
fopen(*argv ".comp", "r");
```

I want to concat the argument with an char[] constant - without the strcat indirection. Is this possible?

Like the "string".$var in PHP or the "a string like this" + var in Java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only concatenate string literals at compile time.

Because compiler has no idea what `*argv` is going to be.

Comment: so I have to use strcat everytime?

Comment: Generally, yes, everytime you need to produce it at runtime.

Comment: Benoit, thought I'd mention `snprintf` in my last comment, but removed it, because in this particular case there's no benefit in it.

Comment: @NaN: Generally, you'll want to use `strncat`, because it's safer.

Comment: Oli, Generally yes, but unimportant when you're appending literal. I'd actually use `memmove`, because I know the size at compile time and know where to put it because I had to determine the size of the original string before allocating memory.